# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 10 path $.item

Tags: php, android, server, retrofit

I want to display data from SqlServer using retrofit in my custom expandable listview. How should my Json Look like to fulfill the following classes parameters?

Here is my current Json;

```
{"item":{"category":"electronics","items":{"title":"Ilara Milk","price":"Ksh 50","url":"http:\/\/supa.swagshop.co.ke\/Images\/coke.jpg"}}}
```

The following is my ShopItem class which takes String and Class Single Item in a List

```
public class ShopItem {
    private String category;
    public List<SingleItem> items = new ArrayList<SingleItem>();

    public ShopItem(String category, List<SingleItem> items) {
        this.category = category;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public List<SingleItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<SingleItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Here is my Single Item class.

```
public class SingleItem {
    private String title;
    private String price;
    private String url;
    private Bitmap itemimage;

    public SingleItem(String title, String price, String url, Bitmap itemimage) {
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.url = url;
        this.itemimage = itemimage;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Bitmap getItemimage() {
        return itemimage;
    }

    public void setItemimage(Bitmap itemimage) {
        this.itemimage = itemimage;
    }
}
```

The following is my Main Fragment, where i'm retrieving data and displaying it on the ExpandableListView using an ExpandableListAdapter

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private BannerSlider bannerSlider;

    private ExpandableListView CategoriesListView;
    private ArrayList<ShopItem> items = new ArrayList<ShopItem>();

    private ExpandableListAdapter categoryAdapter;


    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        bannerSlider = (BannerSlider) view.findViewById(R.id.banner_slider1);

        bannerSlider.addBanner(new RemoteBanner("http://supa.swagshop.co.ke/Images/moto.png"));
        bannerSlider.addBanner(new RemoteBanner("http://supa.swagshop.co.ke/Images/moto.png"));
        bannerSlider.addBanner(new RemoteBanner("http://supa.swagshop.co.ke/Images/moto.png"));
        bannerSlider.addBanner(new RemoteBanner("http://supa.swagshop.co.ke/Images/moto.png"));

        CategoriesListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_items);

        getdata();

        CategoriesListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            int previousGroup = -1;

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if ((previousGroup != -1) && (groupPosition != previousGroup)) {
                    CategoriesListView.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
                }
                previousGroup = groupPosition;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private void getdata() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Items...");
        progressDialog.show();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        InterfaceRequest request = retrofit.create(InterfaceRequest.class);
        Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                    items = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getItem()));
                    categoryAdapter = new ShopItemAdapter(getContext(),items);
                    CategoriesListView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
                } else {
                    Toasty.warning(getContext(),"Oops! Items did not load correctly", Toast.LENGTH_LONG,true).show();
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toasty.error(getContext(),t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,true).show();
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,t.getMessage());
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showData() {
        categoryAdapter = new ShopItemAdapter(getContext(),items);
        CategoriesListView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your model class i assume that you want a category and a list of items. So you should modify your response to be in such a way like

```
{
    "item": {
        "category": "electronics",
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "Ilara Milk",
                "price": "Ksh 50",
                "url": "http://supa.swagshop.co.ke/Images/coke.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If you could post a little bit of your php code, we could help you over that

Comment: There's still an error sir, Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 11 path $.item but now it is at colimn 11 instead of 10

Comment: Could you post your json response ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error describes `items` in your json is an object `items:{..}` but you are trying to convert it to a `list`

The json should be like `items: [item1, item2, ...]`

Comment: can you use the items i've ,mentioned above to explain this @arjun